# Como controlar una excepción al momento de querer verificar mis datos en mi base de datos?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con mi programa JAVA, resulta que tengo este codigo dentro de un jFrame:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{
            String patientID=jTextField1.getText();
            Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from patient where patientID='"+patientID+"'");
            //jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            if(!rs.first()){
                jLabel2.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                jLabel2.setVisible(false);
                jTextField1.setEditable(false);
                flag=1;
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de conexion");
        }
    }
```

Este botón denomindado "BUSCAR" me permite buscar entre mi base de datos PostgreSQL si el id del paciente esta registrado dentro de mi base de datos pero al momento de querer verificar me sale error en la conexión como esta establecido en la Exception. Nose como puedo controlar eso.
De hecho, el jLable2 es la etiqueta para poder verificar si el id del paciente ingresado en el jTextFiel1 está dentro de la base de datos. Si esta no se mostrara la etiqueta, pero si digito un id que no está registrado en la base de datos automáticamente debe mostrarme la etiqueta del label que dice "Este paciente no existe".

```
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

A pesar de que a cada rato me sale el error en la conexión quise verificar si era cierto que no me mostraba los datos en mi aplicación, pero resulta que cuando puse un jTable resulta que si devuelve los valores guardados en mi base de datos PostgreSQL. No sé cómo controlar esa excepción a pesar de que me muestre los datos guardados en mi base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro para poder establecer la conexión desde mi IDE NetBeans hasta PostgreSQL tuve que crear una clase denominada ConnectionProvider:
package Project;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionProvider {
    
    public static Connection getCon(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Hospital","postgres","****");
            return con;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkScrollable(PgResultSet.java:316)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.first(PgResultSet.java:392)
    at addDiagnosisInformation.jButton1ActionPerformed(addDiagnosisInformation.java:246)
    at addDiagnosisInformation$1.actionPerformed(addDiagnosisInformation.java:67)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Estos son algunos de los errores al momento de utilizar este comando de verificacion `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que podamos ver realmente el error que lanza el catch. Podrías editar la pregunta agregando el mensaje que produce `e.printStackTrace()` en tus dos try-catch?

Comment: voy a hacerlo porque primeramente era el error de la excepcion sin agregar el jtable, habia pensado que era tal vez por la conexion a la base de datos pero verifique con la insercion porque ademas de la ventana que presente aqui habia creado una ventana que me servia para poder insertar los datos del pacientes y comprobe que si se guardaban en la base de datos lo cual me resulto raro.

Comment: Hola Javier, has verificado que **jLabel2** este instanciada?.

Comment: Buenas, Javier, bienvenido al sitio. (1) No se trata de un error de conexión, como podemos ver en las trazas. No todas las SQLException son errores de conexión. Deberías escribir el mensaje de la excepción en lugar del texto fijo "Error de conexión". (2) No sé para qué usas la llamada a rs.first(), pero el error te indica que ese ResultSet no acepta la llamada a ese método porque solo puede ir hacia delante. Quizás te valga rs.next(), dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer

Comment: crei que el first me servia para poder traer datos de mi base de datos porque al momento de digitar el id del paciente me devolveria los datos guardados del paciente en mi base de datos

Comment: porque eso es lo que queria que dentro del jframe en el jtable me salga completamente los datos del paciente a traves del id

Comment: si ya corregi mi error porque enserio crei que el first me serviria para devolver mis datos guardados en mi base de datos pero mejor segui tu consejo de ponerlo con el next() y dentro del try corregir ciertas lineas porque ademas de que si no habia ningun registro de ese id cuando lo digitara por teclado me saliera un jlabel que dice no existe el id del paciente